# what the main function in this program returns to os?

Tags: c, recursion

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int fact(int);
int main()
{
    int n=2;
    clrscr();
    return fact(n);
}

int fact(int x)
{
    if(x==0 || x==1)
        return x;
    else
        return fact(x-1);
}
```

It is said that the main function returns `0` upon successful execution and `1` for unsuccessful executions. So what does the above program return to OS? Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: It returns 1 to the OS.

Answer (score 4):

A *convention* has grown up to return 0 for success and non-zero otherwise: The C standard doesn't require you to define success or any specific return value.

Also, some shells only consider the `int` from `main` to be an 8 bit value, so you might want to restrict your possibilities to the range [-127, +127], although that scheme is falling away.

As it stands you program returns `1` back to the calling shell (the fact that it doesn't return `2!` is perhaps a bug). That's idiosyncratic in the sense that using standard input and standard output is more normal. What it chooses to do with that output is down to it.

Comment: you can return any value to the os. The interpretetion is up to the shell script. It can use this value for other reasons